# "EOCD not found" with adb install

Tags: android, windows, adb

When an Android project exceeds about 2MB, I keep getting "EOCD not found, not zip" when trying to install the signed application on a device using adb install. This problem is limited to Windows (Windows XP) because I found no problem installing the same application on a fresh Ubuntu box.

I could reproduce the problem with the HelloWorld application: adb will fail as soon as I add files to exceed 2MB (I generate a 2.7 MB apk file) in the assets folder.

I am almost sure such problem didn't occur in June; unfortunately it seems I can't get back to May/June situation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not seem to be related to size IMO. As in my current project, the APK has size more than 9 MB. I had a similar problem and was getting almost similar logs as below in eclipse console

```
[2011-12-06 10:35:38 - MyProject] Failed to install MyProject.apk on device 
[2011-12-06 10:35:38 - MyProject] (null)
[2011-12-06 10:35:38 - MyProject] Launch canceled!
```

and on window's command console I was getting `EOCD not found, not Zip` message while installing the same APK (build using eclipse). But cleaning and rebuilding the project solved the problem.

In my case, I had had deleted some back up (non-java) files from src directory, which eclipse did not know.

Comment: The cache issue, especially with the SDK 13 and libraries, is something else. Here the problem is different because the apk has been produced successfully and can be sent to the device using the Ubuntu version of adb!