# EOCD not found, not Zip - when trying to install apk in device through cmd prompt

Tags: android, adb, android-maps

I'm creating my first map application for Android and have followed every steps as recommended in [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) article from vogella and I'm unsuccessful in my case. I was facing the **Google Play services is not supported by your device** issue.

Then I came across the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691943/this-app-wont-run-unless-you-update-google-play-services-via-bazaar/13734937#13734937) that suggests manually uploading few apks in the emulator to get going with the maps. I was successful till step 2 in following that post but failed in step 3 that recommends to install **com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk** and **com.google.android.gms-2.apk** using the adb command.

I got the following issue in the command prompt

```
EOCD not found, not Zip
file 'D:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\apks\com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk'
is not a valid zip file
rm failed for /data/local/tmp/com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk, No such file or directory
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353332/eocd-not-found-not-zip-shows-error-when-install-apk), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649625/eocd-not-found-not-zip-while-installing-apk-without-source) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286233/eocd-not-found-with-adb-install) but those didn't help either.

**Update:**

One of post that I came across recommended to email ourselves and open the email account in the emulator and download the files and then install from there. I followed the steps and was successful in having those apk files in the emulator but I faced issue when installing those. The following is the exception i received in the dialog

> There is a problem parsing the package.

I believe the issue could be because of corrupted file? I have the latest SKDs updated. The emulator configuration can be seen in [this screenshot](http://sdrv.ms/1cUMMsW)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it turned out just to be that the actual apk file was corrupt. You should be able to open the APK on your machine using a zip file manager, if you cannot then it maybe that the file is corrupt.

Try downloading a new one again maybe from a different source and check that you can open it as a zip file before transferring.

Comment: In my case, downloading it via firefox allowed me to actually install the app. When i download THAT SAME apk package, i get the "parsing error".

Comment: For us, using the DuckDuckGo Android Browser was corrupting the APK file. Using a different one worked.